# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable while sending text to contenteditable div element

Tags: python, selenium, contenteditable, sendkeys, webdriverwait

I am having trouble with a selenium send keys on discord. I am attempting to send a message to a user.

The error I get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

The HTML is as follows:
[image: HTML]

The Object im trying to `send_keys` that is highlighted by the xpath is as follows:
[image]

My code is as follows

```
inputMessage = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Message @')]/..")))

#inputMessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Message @')]/..") 

inputMessage.send_keys(msg,Keys.ENTER)
```

I have attempted several ways to try to solve the error but have not succeeded. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can wait for element to visible and when element found send keys WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'Your_element_xpath')))

Comment: looks like you're trying to use send_keys on a div. I'll look up what elements is allowed but I'd think an input element is ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ElementNotInteractableException` error tells you that you can't use the send_keys() method on this webElement. I can't really tell you what could work, considering the lack of information considering the problem, but here are some clues :

- Using the ActionsChains to try to input what you want in the field:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.send_keys('your_data')
actions.perform()
```

- Try `inputMessage.click()` before you try to send keys

Otherwise, it happened to me too, and the thing was that i tried to send keys to the div, and not to the  element which was inside it.

Hopes it help !

Comment: Exactly. @BigO tries to press enter on a div, but he probably want to press enter on an input field.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML contenteditable Attribute

By using some JavaScript event handlers you can transform your web page into a full and fast rich text editor only by setting the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute on nearly any HTML element to make it editable. As an example, to create a `<div>` element whose contents an user can edit would be:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

When an HTML element has `contenteditable` set to `true`, the [`document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method is made available. This lets you run [commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand#Commands) to manipulate the contents of the editable region. However, there seem to be some difference in usage of `contenteditable` across different browsers. As an example, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> to create a new line of text inside an editable element:

- Firefox inserted `<br>` elements
- IE/Opera used `<p>` elements
- Chrome/Safari used `<div>` elements
- Firefox 60 wraps the separate lines in `<div>` elements, matching the behavior of Chrome, modern Opera, Edge, and Safari.

---

### This usecase

As per the HTML it seems the next `<div>` with attribute `aria-label="Message @Ticketing"` has the property **`contenteditable="true"`**. So ideally you should be able to invoke `send_keys()` on this element.

---

### Solution

Finally, to interact with an element you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Message @Ticketing'][data-slate-editor='true'][role='textbox']"))).send_keys(msg)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Message @Ticketing' and @data-slate-editor='true'][@role='textbox']"))).send_keys(msg)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

An edited version of @MatthiasDec answer:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver) 
actions.move_to_element(inputMessage) 
actions.send_keys('your_data')
actions.perform()
```